# How to best align numbers and text in one column?

Tags: text, alignment, numbers

I am struggling with small redesign of our app's screens. I have a few labels + values (one under the other) which contain numerical and text data.
Another complication is that some of those numeric values do not have decimal places

I am struggling how to best align that mix so that do not look all over the place. What I have come up with are 3 alternative versions:

Which one do you think is best?
Version 1 aligns the numbers to the decimal point
version 2 aligns the numbers to the right
Version 3 is pretty much the same as ver 2, only it aligns the text to the right as well.
These fields are related so I should not really change their order.
I think version 1 is best, but would like to know your opinion as well.
[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or a mock up of your problem.

Comment: Put the currency in front of the monetary values, preferably in a separate column. If it must be in the same column: align it to the left - certainly don't make it move position with the length of the monetary value. Align numbers on the decimal position. Add `--` for discrete (non-decimal) numbers in light gray or some such and of course without the decimal separator. Keep textual values right aligned as that mixes better with the numerical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

In my comment I said:

> Put the currency in front of the monetary values, preferably in a
>   separate column. If it must be in the same column: align it to the
>   left - certainly don't make it move position with the length of the
>   monetary value. Align numbers on the decimal position. Add -- for
>   discrete (non-decimal) numbers in light gray or some such and of
>   course without the decimal separator. Keep textual values right
>   aligned as that mixes better with the numerical alignment.

This is a picture of what I meant (no pictures in comments):

[image]

**Note**: keeping text right aligned may only the best option if the numerical values "swamp" the textual ones. If/when you have significantly more textual values than numerical ones, it is probably better to keep the text left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Context is most important here, and I think in this case the context dulls it towards numbers presentation and ability to compare them. This is why I think it's no good to have these numbers shifted depending on if they do have something after decimal pont or not - because by doing it you remove this ability.

Regarding text, I would use diffferent styling (background maybe?), so that it sticks out.

You can also consider always showing decimals - in my opinion this will increase the clarity of the numbers presentation.

Here's my idea:

[image]

Comment: I should have mentioned before:

Comment: Thanks, but I should have mentioned this before: 
the first field is a "quantity" field so it must 
not have "USD" next to it. 
Also - the number of decimals can vary between the fields, 
so it is not always two decimals. 
E.g. Numeric (non decimal) has no decimals in 90% of cases, 
but some times it can have up to 6 
(depending on the formatting config). 
Fields I marked as "Numeric(decimal)" have 2 decimals 
in 90% of cases.

Comment: This changes everything, indeed. In this case I think you should do the opposite: not let these be comparable, preferably by splitting them, dividing visually. But this is generalizing. Do you think you could provide some more details about the system?

Answer (score 0):

Decimal numbers should always align on the decimal.

In desktop publishing software, you'd use a decimal tab stop just for this. It's what it was designed for. In HTML, alas, this can be a bit tricky as there is no concept of the decimal tab stop.

There are two solutions:

1. Use monospaced fonts, make sure every number has the same number of decimal places (even if zeros) and right-align the text. Pro = easy. Con = can't guarantee it will show up for every end user as a monospaced font (depending on browser and system settings, etc.)
2. Get crafty with your CSS: http://jsbin.com/jecuyeqi/1/ Pro: it's font independent. Con: takes more markup.

What you need to do is wrap the decimals in their own container separate from the whole numbers:

```
<span class="number">123<span class="decimal">.345</span></span>
```

You then float the decimal to the right, and then give it a width, and set the text to left-align:

```
.number {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}

.decimal {
  width: 100px; 
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
}
```

(There are variations to the above as well. For instance, you could skip the floating and set .decimal to display: inline-block. But the concept is all the same)

Answer (score 0):

If the first field is a quantity for an item then it's probably best not to align in and instead make them in one line:

```
Item 1       10 x 300 USD
```

or

```
10 x Item 1 @300USD         3000 USD
```

Your version 1 is, IMO, horrible; it implies similarity where there is none. Similar things should look similar, while different things should look different.